# Trying to write simple hello world to firebase database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write to my firebase Realtime database but I cannot figure why I cant. I'm just starting to implement it but I cant figure out why my .setValue()in my onCreate is not working. I've brought in my google-servies doc and i've followed the code in the tutorial in android studio but still no luck. I also dont think its an error with dependences but it still could be for all i know. I'm not getting any errors so im really at a lost.  Has anybody any suggestions. Here is the relevant code:

```
class CreateAPostFragment : Fragment() {

var post = PostModel()
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("HERE IS MY URL TO THE DATABASE")
val myRef = database.getReference("test")




override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    myRef.setValue("Hello World")
    println("added")
    println(myRef)
```

}

Build.gradle(Project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

   task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

build.gradle(module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ie.wit.savvytutor"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you got a pic of your database? Does it have a node called "test"? If not, it is normal you will not write anything

Comment: Hey Francesco, brand new to stack overflow so i don't have the reputation to post pictures of my db. When i run the the app i think the node is created but nothing writes into it so i have: myDatabaseName -> Test and then nothing in test...Sorry if that's not relating to your question

Comment: Instead of including a picture of the JSON tree in your question, post the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but i cannot write anything into my DB so when i export it, it just says null.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue("Hello World")` to see if something is wrong?